# Selected ListBox Value does not sets into textbox binded value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, prism

The listbox selected value while displays on textbox UI but does not set to the value I wanted to bind it.
xaml code

```
     <TextBlock
                x:Name ="TargetAmplitudeValue"
                Margin="6,0,0,0"
                Text="{Binding ElementName=AmplitudeListBox, Path=SelectedItem.AmplitudeValue}" />

<ListBox x:Name="AmplitudeListBox"
            Grid.Row="6"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Height="Auto"
            ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ListBoxItemsPanelTemplate}"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedAmplitudeItemIndex}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border x:Name="ampstborder"  MinWidth="50" MinHeight="40" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Margin="20,10,0,10">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="amplitudeValue" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=AmplitudeValue}"></TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

[selected value][1]

But I want that value to be in the variable and I was previously binding this variable to textbox as I will be needing this value in different method.

viewmodel code

```
     private double targetAmplitude;

        public double TargetAmplitude
        {
            get => this.targetAmplitude;

            set
            {
                this.targetAmplitude = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.CanExecuteOKCommand));
               // If current area amplitude is greater than target amplitude set the step interval as "OFF"
                if (this.CurrentAmplitude > this.TargetAmplitude)
                {
                    this.SelectedRampSpeed = this.RampSpeedItemList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RampSpeedItemName == RampSpeedItem.None);
                }

                // If current area amplitude is less than target amplitude set the default step interval i.e. 1
                if (this.CurrentAmplitude < this.TargetAmplitude && this.SelectedRampSpeed.RampSpeedItemName == RampSpeedItem.None)
                {
                    this.SelectedRampSpeed = this.defaultRampSpeed;
                    this.IsDefaultStepInterval = true;
                }

                this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.TargetAmplitude));
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.MessageText));
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.IsDisplayMessage));
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.IsTargetAmplitudeSelected));
            }
        }
```

variable in method

[variable][2]

I just want to know how to retrieve value from listbox and set it to this textbox/variable also textbox should be updated on new selected value from listbox
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gQ4m.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9XG3.jpg

Comment: How do you set the `ItemsSource` of `AmplitudeListBox`? Your sample code is a mess. Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the SelectedItem of the listbox to AmplitudeValue

```
<ListBox x:Name="AmplitudeListBox" 
      SelectedItem={binding AmplitudeValue}
      ....
```

in ViewModel

```
private double amplitudeValue;
public AmplitudeValue 
      {
        get{ return amplitudeValue } }
        set{ 
           amplitudeValue = value; 
           this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.AmplitudeValue));
        }
      }
```

in

```
 <TextBlock
                x:Name ="TargetAmplitudeValue"
                Margin="6,0,0,0"
                Text="{Binding Path=AmplitudeValue}" />
```

Comment: It is showing listbox value on textBox but how do I set this value to  variable to be used in one of the method of viewmodel?

Comment: Updated the answer hope it works

Comment: Listbox selected item is not showing in the textbox and as soon as I'm selecting the textbox, there is red border coming on listbox. Listbox itemsource is binded to Observable collection.

Comment: change mode bothway. on textbox binding, please check if the AmplitudeValue set get hit bu debugger when you change the list

Comment: I have checked with debugger. On selecting one of the item of listbox debug doesn't stops on it